# Is it possible to @extend Foundation SCSS classes?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

Using the tools provided by Zurb's Foundation as they were intended means you have to compromise your HTML-markup. You'll be adding classes the HTML doesn't need just to pull in that Foundation functionality.

Using the SASS source code I'm trying to avoid aforementioned problem by using `@extend`.

---

Some example HTML markup I want to avoid

```
<nav id="main_navigation" class="top-bar">
```

By doing this

```
#main_navigation {
  @extend .top-bar;
}
```

---

I realise this would still compile to redundant CSS as well as probably break the JS functionality for the topbar, but let's save that for another question.

The issue is that it doesn't work! Styles that apply to children of `.top-bar` as well as any pseudo-classes don't get extended to apply to `#main_navigation`. I tried to [recreate the problem in a CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iLyFb/right/?editors=010), but the compiled code over there is flawless.

So is this a structural problem in Foundation? Or am I messing something up?

I use a Grunt task with grunt-sass to compile the Foundation SASS with my own code after it.

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't explain the problem.  Is there an error (what is it?)?  Sass will either throw an error if the selector is not extendable or it will extend the selector.

Comment: @cimmanon Styles that apply to children of .top-bar as well as any pseudo-classes don't get extended to apply to #main_navigation. (Quoting the actual following sentence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more extensive debugging using CodePen I figured the issue had to be in the compiler.

Switching from `grunt-sass` to the more stable (but slower) `grunt-contrib-sass` made all unexpected behavior disappear.

Yes, you can `@extend` Foundation SCSS